# How to fetch specific column values have more than x rows in php?

Tags: php, mysql

In my MySQL 'purchase' table one column stores user_name, as every finished purchase is stored here along with other details such as shopping_cart_id, amount, i want to fetch what are the user_name have more than 10/50/100 purchases.

I can get the number of purchase record for every users, but i want to filter the results by number of rows. Here is my query for getting the number of records for every user.

```
$query = MySQL_query("SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM purchase GROUP BY user_name ORDER BY count DESC") or  die(MySQL_error());
```

thanks

Comment: You can use sql's HAVING statement. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-group-by-having/

Answer (score 1):

Use `HAVING` clause

```
SELECT user_name, 
COUNT(*) as count1 
FROM purchase 
GROUP BY user_name 
HAVING COUNT(*) IN (100, 50, 10)
ORDER BY count1 DESC
```

(OR) Use a outer select and filter the same like

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT user_name, 
COUNT(*) as count1 
FROM purchase 
GROUP BY user_name ) xx
WHERE count1 IN (100, 50, 10)
ORDER BY count1 DESC
```

Comment: Thanks, your first code gave me the result of users  who have exactly  10, 50, 100  purchases. But i wanted to have users who have purchased more than x number of purchase. May be, my question may not be more clear.

Comment: @user4093, in that case change the condition to be `> x`

Answer (score 0):

I added an if statement within my while loop and it worked fine. I know there many more ways to achieve this result. My code:

```
$query = MySQL_query("SELECT user_name, COUNT(*) as count FROM purchase    GROUP BY user_name ORDER BY count DESC") or die(MySQL_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
 {
  $user_name = $row["user_name"];
  $num_rows = $row['count'];
  if($num_rows > '100'){
  echo $user_name."&nbsp;&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;&nbsp;".$num_rows."<br>";
 } 
}
```

This code retrieved all user_name who have more than 100 purchases, from higher to lower.